# Nginx + PHP7-FPM Content-Type empty $FILES

Tags: php, file, nginx, upload, php-7

When I try to send files using **PostMan** and the **Content-Type** header is set to any kind of values the $FILES array is completely empty.

**If i remove this header I could see the file in the array.**

I've tried a lot of different values for that header but none seems to work.

The problem is that I'm working with an external supplier and theirs software couldn't remove that header from their POST request

With the following configuration:

- **Nginx/1.12.2**
- **PHP 7.0.28**

**And the following config on the nginx vhost:**

```
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
```

Comment: What are you setting the header value to?

Comment: Any kind of value of the header Content-Type give me this problem, only if i don't set the header the $FILES is populated correctly

Comment: What values have you tried thuugh?

Comment: Any kind of values as said above

Comment: Helpful. Good luck.

Comment: It will be helpful if you provide some kind of extra explanation and cmiiw, what you mean by $FILES is $_FILES from file upload API right? And you are trying to upload those files from postman? what is the form type? form-data? x-www-form-urlencoded? raw? binary?

Comment: Have you tried adding `fastcgi_hide_header "Content-Type";` to your n?ginx config

Answer (score 3):

For `$_FILES` to work, you should send the header `content-type` set to `multipart/form-data`. When you set it to anything else, the server won't know how to get the file you sent.

The request body should also be in the format that `multipart/form-data` requires. This is done by the file upload libraries automatically (and browsers).

Now, the reason why it works when you remove the `content-type` header is Postman automatically adds it in when you include a file in your request, and formats the whole request as `multipart/form-data` format.